# Copy rows from a sheet with conditional format and use CF of new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro on vba that cuts a Row from sheet A and pastes it on sheet B. Sheet A and Sheet B have conditional formattings, but differ.

This is what my macro is doing

```
Sub MoveToSent()
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim C As Long

'Define sheets to use
Dim wsOrigin As Excel.Worksheet, _
    wsDestiny As Excel.Worksheet, _
    xRg As Excel.Range
 
Set wsOrigin = Worksheets("FOLLOWING")
Set wsDestiny = Worksheets("SENT")

'Number or rows of sheets
A = wsOrigin.UsedRange.Rows.Count
B = wsDestiny.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If B = 3 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsDestiny.UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
End If
'Select column F, from 4 (first data row) till last number
Set xRg = wsOrigin.Range("F4:F" & A)
On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For C = 1 To xRg.Count
    If Not Len(Trim(xRg(C).Value)) = 0 Then
        'xRg(C).EntireRow.FormatConditions.Delete
        xRg(C).EntireRow.Range("A" & C & ":H" & C).Copy Destination:=wsDestiny.Range("A" & B + 1)
        xRg(C).EntireRow.Delete
        If Not Len(Trim(xRg(C).Value)) = 0 Then
            C = C - 1
        End If
        B = B + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I tried using the FormatConditions.Delete, as you can see, but that deletes the formatcondition so hardly that, when pasted on the new sheet, doesnt get applied the new FC supposed.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: You'd need to delete the FC from the pasted row(s), and then apply the new CF to those pasted rows.  Try recording a macro to see how the needed FC is applied.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go into that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based into what Tim suggested, I went into this:

Pasting from Sheet A into Sheet B

```
Set rgDestiny = wsDestiny.Range("A" & B + 1 & ":H" & B + 1)
'Delete CF from origin
rgDestiny.FormatConditions.Delete
'And add new CF 
Set cond1 = rgDestiny.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($G" & B + 1 & "));ESFECHA($G" & B + 1 & "))")
Set cond2 = rgDestiny.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($F" & B + 1 & "));($B$1 - UTILITIES!$E$4) >= $F" & B + 1 & ")")
Set cond3 = rgDestiny.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($F" & B + 1 & "));($B$1 - UTILITIES!$E$3) >= $F" & B + 1 & ")")
With cond1
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 50
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
End With
With cond2
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
End With
With cond3
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
End With
```

Delete Row from Sheet A

By doing so, I add 3CF for each row, which is fairly close to what I want (I would prefer having only 3 CF instead of 3*rownum, but nevermind).

Hope this helps anyone who finds the same problem! Spent quite a few hours googling and didn't find any way to copy data from a sheet and pasting and applying different CF than they had, so the workaround is Delete the CF they have and add them mannualy via VBA.